# Confusion in TCL substitution

Tags: regex, tcl

I am confused with the following statements .

1. ```
   % set a \\\\\w
   \\w
   ```
2. ```
   % set a \\\\w
   \\w
   ```
3. ```
   % set a \\w
   \w
   ```

In the First statement I am having 5 (backslashes) and it produced 2 (backslashes) as output.

In the second statement I am having 4 (backslashes) and it produced 2 (backslashes) as output.

In the Third statement I am having 2 (backslashes) and it produced 1 (backslashes) as output.

Up to my knowledge `\\` is equal to `\` after substitution .

As it is `\\\\\` it should return single `\` na.

Can Anyone Please Explain me how the substitution occures.

Comment: Use `/` in filenames on windows (and `file nativename` to convert, if needed for external programs) and put your regular expressions in `{` braces `}`. This deals with the two most common cases of backslash confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is [simple](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M16):

- There are some special subsitutions, including `\\` will be substituted into `\`, so `\\\\` will be replaced with `\\` (not a single `\`). For a list of all special substitutions, see the [manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M16).
- On other escape sequences (like `\w`) the backslash will be removed. From the [manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M16):

> In all cases but those described below the backslash is dropped and the following character is treated as an ordinary character and included in the word.

Comment: On other escape sequences (like \w) the backslash will be removed. Can you explain this statement . as i am getting same for special characters as well as non special characters % set a \\\\\\\946
\\\946
%

Comment: ok, ``\\``,``\\``,``\\``,``\946`` becomes ``\``,``\``,``\``,`946`.